# How to get position of an element from a nested list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

If I have a list that looks like this

```
list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,'X'], [7,8,'X']]
```

How can I get the position of X i.e like (i,j)?

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get the "address" of 'X' in i, j notation.  In the example, there are two instances of 'X', so we will need to account for returning an arbitrary number of index-tuples

Comment: @Georgy thanks i found the solution. Using enumerate helps

Answer (score 3):

`list` is a python keyword so it is probably better to use some other name. To access an element of list you can use this syntax: `listname[indexNumber]`. Note that index starts from 0. So, to access the X in the second list in the nested loop, you  need to access the second list first; like this `secondList = list[1]`. Then you can get X which is in the second index position. `x = secondList[2]`. You can do this in the same line as well: `print(list[1][2])`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the "outer" list and use `index` on the inner list:

```
def find(matrix, item):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        try: 
            j = matrix[i].index(item)
            return (i, j)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError # If item isn't found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,'X'], [7,8,'X']] 


print(list1[1][2])
print(list1[2][2])
```

If you don't know where 'X' will be every time:

```
test_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,'X'], [7,8,'X']] 

x = None
y = None

for separate_list in test_list:
    for var in separate_list:
        if var == 'X':
            if x == None:
                x = var
            elif y == None:
                y = var
            
pos = (x,y)

print(pos)
```

Comment: what if the list changes

Comment: A nested for loop would take care of that, I just thought it was a definite position

Comment: @AstroLion i tried this. But it gives this output ([4,5,X], 3)

Comment: @PrathamDave Are you sure you copied it right? I get ('X', 'X') as an output

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list slicing.

```
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,'X'], [7,8,'X']]

print(l[0][0], l[1][2], l[2][0])

print(l[1][2])
 
# [0][0] == first list in list and first item in the first list
# [1][2] == second list and third item in the second list
# [2][0] == third list and first item in that list
```

ouput

```
1 X 7

X
```

great python list slicing tuto [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/amp/)